# Configure: Error: Libgds, Libib_util or Libfbclient Not Found

Tags: php, firebird1.5

I'm trying to set php working with firebird 1.5 on my mac os

But i got this message when to try set up follow by this tutorial

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php

Anybody have solution for that ?

Comment: First of all: do you really want to use Firebird 1.5, and not the more recent 2.5? Do you actually have a libfbclient on your machine?

Comment: Thanks about your comment. Yes. I need 1.5 because that is requirement of probject. I got this error "Configure: Error: Libgds, Libib_util or Libfbclient not found" on my mac but i dont know how to add it. I dont know how to check it exist in my machine. Do you have solution for update it ?

Comment: I don't have a mac, but have you looked at the first comment on the link in your question?